# How do the deprecated commitment levels map to the later ones?

Tags: commitment

Version 1.5.5 deprecated a host of `Commitment` levels, as seen in the code here:

```
export type Commitment =
  | 'processed'
  | 'confirmed'
  | 'finalized'
  | 'recent' // Deprecated as of v1.5.5
  | 'single' // Deprecated as of v1.5.5
  | 'singleGossip' // Deprecated as of v1.5.5
  | 'root' // Deprecated as of v1.5.5
  | 'max'; // Deprecated as of v1.5.5
```

How do the deprecated commitment levels map to the ones currently in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecations are documented in the code as part of [this commit](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/14797/commits/c3e71284e9ba53888b9b1f0481a8d166ce5d31f3).

- `max` and `root` imply `finalized`
- `singleGossip` and `single` imply `confirmed`
- `recent` implies `processed`